# How to read Images from Excel Sheets using OpenXMLSDK and C#?

Tags: c#, .net, openxml-sdk

We are developing C# winform application.We are using OpenXMLSDK for accessing and modifying Excel sheets.Now i want to read the imgaes from excel sheets using Open XML SDK.Please Guide me to get out of this issue.

Thanks & Regards,
P.SARAVANAN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the image parts, get the image part reference, read from the stream to get the image.

Comment: Can you give more details on it? I'm looking for reading an image from the excel file into a data table